# Get multiple cells as input for Table connection

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get input from multiple cells and sheets to create a Query and then use that query for the connection.

I copied a Module that is used in a different Excel file and does the same job for a PivotTable, but I would like to have it work with a normal Table.

**Overview excel file:**

Sheet "Settings" with a list of names that have to be used to filter.

Sheet "All Incidents 2014" with a Table that has the connection and has to be refreshed with the new query.

Sheet "SQL" that has the Query I would like to use without WHERE statement. Also the Connection String has been put down here.

I've a feeling that the row underneath is wrong normally you would use .PivotTable if it is a PivotTable, but this time it's a Table. I would like to know what I have to use to get this to work with a Table.

```
Set tab_I = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All Incidents 2014").Range("A1").TableObject

Module:
--------------------------------------

Function Update_2014()

'-----------------------------------------------------------------

Dim in_sql As String

Dim sql_I1 As String

Dim tab_I As TableObject

Dim connection As String

'-----------------------------------------------------------------

in_sql = ""

sql_I1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SQL").Range("A1").Value

Set tab_I = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All Incidents 2014").Range("A1").PivotTable

connection = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SQL").Range("B1")

'-----------------------------------------------------------------

For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Range("C5:C500")

    If s.Value = "" Then
        in_sql = in_sql
    Else
        in_sql = in_sql & "'%" & s.Value & "%'," '& vbCrLf
    End If

Next s

in_sql = Left(in_sql, Len(in_sql) - 1)

'-----------------------------------------------------------------

tab_I.PivotCache.connection = "OLEDB;"

sql_I1 = sql_I1 & ", table (sys.odcivarchar2list (" & in_sql & ")) Where SERVICE like column_value"

tab_I.PivotCache.CommandText = sql_I1

tab_I.PivotCache.connection = connection

'-----------------------------------------------------------------

tab_I.Refresh

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following solution:

```
Set pt_I = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheetname").ListObjects("Table_name")
```